# Shiny - update radio buttons based on date range input

Tags: r, shiny

[image]I have a Shiny dashboard which uses the inputs for the tables as seen on the picture. There are radio buttons and date range input, which is used only when the radio button is switched to `Custom` . Is there a way the radio button is switched instantly to `Custom` when the user clicks on the date range picker or changes the date (does not matter which one of those two options)?

Here is the minimal example to print the selected range:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Reproducible example",
                         
                         tabPanel("Example", 
                                  div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; margin-right: 20px", radioButtons(inputId = "select_range", 
                                                                                                                         label = "Choose the date:", 
                                                                                                                         choices = c("Yesterday", "Last week", "Last month", "Last 7 days", "Last 30 days", "Custom"),
                                                                                                                         selected = c("Yesterday"),
                                                                                                                         inline=TRUE)),
                                  div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 220px;", dateRangeInput("daterange_custom",
                                                                                                                      "",
                                                                                                                      start = Sys.Date() - days(20),
                                                                                                                      end = Sys.Date() - days(1),
                                                                                                                      min = as.Date("2023-01-01"),
                                                                                                                      max = Sys.Date() - days(1),
                                                                                                                      format = "dd.mm.yyyy",
                                                                                                                      separator = "-",
                                                                                                                      weekstart = 1)),
                                  htmlOutput("print_daterange")))) 



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$print_daterange <- renderText({
    
    
    
    #based on the selected button set the time range
    if (input$select_range  == "Yesterday"){
      
      range_start <- Sys.Date() - 1
      range_end <- Sys.Date() - 1
      
      
    } else if (input$select_range  == "Last week"){
      
      range_start <- floor_date(Sys.Date(), "weeks", week_start = 1) %m-% weeks(1)
      range_end <- ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "weeks", week_start = 1) %m-% weeks(1) - 1
      
      
      
    } else if (input$select_range  == "Last month"){
      
      range_start <- floor_date(Sys.Date(), "months") %m-% months(1)
      range_end <- ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "months") %m-% months(1) - 1
      
      
      
    } else if (input$select_range  == "Last 7 days"){
      
      range_start <- Sys.Date() - 7
      range_end <- Sys.Date() - 1
      
    } else if (input$select_range  == "Last 30 days"){
      
      range_start <- Sys.Date() - 30
      range_end <- Sys.Date() - 1
      
    } else if (input$select_range  == "Custom"){
      
      range_start <- input$daterange_custom[1]
      range_end <- input$daterange_custom[2]
      
    }
    
    
    paste("Daterange is", range_start, "-", range_end)
    
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried the following chunk of code, but this basically disallows selecting any other radio buttons than Custom, as it apparently does not detect changes.

```
observeEvent(input$daterange_custom, {
      updateRadioButtons(session, "select_range", selected = "Custom")})
```

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @TarJae Sure, I have updated the question with a basic example to print the date range.

Comment: @Honza88 I believe your `observeEvent` should work, and will trigger if the custom date changes. If you noticed that "Custom" becomes the default when you start the app, that is because the `observeEvent` will also trigger upon start up. To prevent this, add `ignoreINIT = T` such as: `observeEvent(input$daterange_custom, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "select_range", selected = "Custom")
  }, ignoreInit = T)`